# An unrelated domain is pointing to my website and appears to be using my SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, dns, server

I run a website affectionaries.com that has a valid SSL certificate hosted by Hostgator.

It has come to my attention that when searching in Google for terms such as "Affectionaries" or "Cupcakes Runcorn" an other domain appears higher up the SERP's using my meta data an is unrelated to my business. If you click the link for (https://www.miamiboxpanama.com/) then it takes you to an insecure warning page! Under advanced it tells you:

www.miamiboxpanama.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: affectionaries.com, www.affectionaries.com Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I can not figure out what is going on here...

So far I can see that this domain is on the same nameservers and IP address as my site.

Has anyone have experience with this and know a solution to resolve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

`www.miamiboxpanama.com` resolves to the same IP address as `affectionaries.com` (192.254.231.2). So both names lead to the exact same web server, and therefore also the exact same SSL certificate. Since that certificate is only for the name `affectionaries.com`, the browser correctly issues a warning when the name it used was `www.miamiboxpanama.com`.

This looks like a configuration error at Hostgator. You may want to contact them and ask what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this was pretty much the same conclusion I have arrived at.

I have been in contact with Hostgator on live chat for over 2 hours with no help whatsoever. Furthermore they have responded to my support ticket with telling me this is how it should work!?

Any advice on what I can do? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hostgator have finally pulled their finger and put me on a dedicated IP address. This does help slightly as the rogue domain does not route to my site... however I am still concerned that the result shows up in Google search. Does anyone know if Google will reindex the rogue site and remove from SERPS once they realise there is no site there?